# Gitlab ldap how to replace name field with last_name and first_name

Tags: authentication, gitlab, ldap

How to replace the name field with last_name and first_name? Through the attribute setting, the value is not pulled from ldap. What could be the problem?

I change the configuration with the `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command

I tried to delete the user through the admin panel and create again after applying the configuration

```
gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'AD'
     host: 'example.com'
     port: 389
     uid: 'sAMAccountName'
     bind_dn: 'CN=gitlab,OU=general,DC=example,DC=com'
     password: 'pass'
     encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
     verify_certificates: false
#     tls_options: { verify_mode: 'OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE', ca_file: '', ssl_version: '', ciphers: '', cert: '', key: '' }
     smartcard_auth: false
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: false
     lowercase_usernames: true
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'DC=example,DC=com'
     user_filter: ''
     attributes:
        username: ['uid', 'userid', 'sAMAccountName']
        email: ['mail', 'email', 'userPrincipalName']
        name: 'cn'
        first_name: 'givenName'
        last_name: 'sn'
EOS
```

[LDAP attributes example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvJtu.png)

[The fields in the database remain empty.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzsWR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an empty string so that it falls back to using first+last name.

Quoted from the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/auth/ldap/index.html#attribute-configuration-settings) :

> **name** : LDAP attribute for user display name. If name is blank, the full name is taken from the `first_name` and `last_name`.
>
> Attributes `'cn'`, or `'displayName'` commonly carry full names.
> Alternatively, you can force the use of `first_name` and `last_name` by
> specifying an absent attribute such as `'somethingNonExistent'`.

Comment: Tried, didn't help

Comment: The official documentation is literally answering your question here, so maybe you are asking the wrong question, and/or the problem comes from first_name and last_name not being properly provisioned in the first place, or .. in fact, with no further information than _didn't help_, it's hard to tell. You can still edit your post, describe how you are actually testing the config, with which user (ldap record sample with sn and givenName attributes), where you expect _name_ to show up, what are the logs saying, etc.